# SQL Insert For Multiple Records At Once With a One Row Table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I've found that Access doesn't allow Insert Into queries for multiple records unless using a Select query from a one row table. Still, it doesn't work and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

- I'm trying to insert into `tblTarget`, which contains 3 fields: ID, F1, F2 (Respectively auto number, number, number).
- I have created a table `onerow`. I'm not exactly sure how it should be created, so right now it has the fields: ID, F1, F2 (Identical fields to the target table), with only one row (Empty row, except for the ID). Note that I haven't programmed the table to allow only one row, it just has only one at the moment.
- The query:

  ```
  INSERT INTO tblTarget (F1, F2)
  SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT '31','3' FROM onerow
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '31','2' FROM onerow);
  ```
- Error I receive: "The Insert Into statement contains the following unknown field name: 'Expr1000'. Make sure you have typed correctly, and try the operation again.

My instincts say the problem is with the `onerow` table, but I can't figure out the solution.

Comment: I believe you don't need the outer query and just stick with using the UNION ALL

Comment: You might also want to alias your columns.

Comment: Without the outer query I receive the error: "Syntax Error in FROM clause"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me in Access 2010:

```sql
INSERT INTO tblTarget (F1, F2)
SELECT *
FROM
    (
        SELECT 31 AS F1, 3 AS F2 FROM onerow
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 31, 2 FROM onerow
    )
```

The trick was to specify the field names in the first of the UNION-ed queries so the names matched those in the INSERT clause.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
Insert into UserData(UserName,Password)
Select 'user1','abc'
Union All
Select 'user2','abc'
```

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''abc' Union All Select 'user2''.